# Numbers instead of name for login email for security?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Our Active Directory logins are currently e.g. john.smith@mycompany.com (i.e. the same as our email addresses).  A friend said they used a number for login (e.g. 38292@mycompany.com) for security reasons.  The login being internal and not public facing.

Wondering what others think/do and what is considered best practice.  Thank you.

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, which isn't a good fit for StackOverflow, which is for coding. Maybe try https://security.stackexchange.com
But using numbers as usernames is really just security by obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, as your friend said it is a good practice to keep your internal login ids and email ids as login ids different for several reasons. One of them is that if you have several people by the same names or similar spelling then it can be very hectic and weary to trace down a user’s activity across large span of internal environment presence. So, its best to keep internal application login different than email address as it helps your internal security team to continuously monitor and prevent threats like spamming a particular mailbox, sending phishing mails, etc. Also, it keeps your organization’s internal infrastructure at bay from attackers as brute force attacks through email ids are not at all possible since employee id numbers aren’t public.

•   You can do so by configuring email address attribute for your users for which you can set the one containing employee number as their primary email address and other one configured, i.e., email address(firstname.lastname) as your employees’ alias email address or proxy addresses.

[image: Homerealmdiscovery policy]

•   Once, that is set, then you need to enable users to sign in with email address as alternate login ID. This feature tells the Azure AD login servers to not only check the sign-in identifier against UPN values, but also against ProxyAddresses values for the email address. This can be done through the ‘homerealmdiscoverypolicy’ resource as given in detail in the below link for your reference: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-use-email-signin#enable-user-sign-in-with-an-email-address